# Python - Running Curl against a text file

Tags: python, curl

I have a text file called "sites.txt" full of URLs. I'm trying to tell python to read the file and run "curl -I" against all URLs contained in the text file. Is this possible or is there an easier way to get the status codes for multiple websites at once?

What I'm trying to accomplish is seeing what sites return a 200 status and which sites return a 404 error in a list of 100 sites. I can go through all sites individually but that will be very times consuming.

I've tried a few things but always get stuck at how to run a command inside a python script.

```
from subprocess import curl

f = open('sites.txt', "r")
lines = f.readlines()
curl (["-I"])
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Try using the [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) module or even easier (but requiring an install) use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module

Comment: you are having problem in reading file?

Comment: Thanks wilbur I'll give both a shot. Vivek, I can read the file just can't run the curl command.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426563/curling-in-python-and-outputting-into-individual-text-files