# Curling in Python and Outputting into Individual Text Files

Tags: python, html, url, curl

How do you read multiple lines containing say 3 URLs from a .txt file, "curl" them to extract the HTML, and output them all to their own individual files in python?
I've tried-

```
    import commands
    import os
    import json

    # RAW DATA
    input = open('uri.txt', 'r')
    t_1 = open('command', 'w')
    counter_1 = 0

    for line in input:
          counter_1 += 1
    if counter_1 < 3:
          filename = str(counter_1)
          print str(line)
    filename= str(count)
    command ='curl ' + '"' + str(line).rstrip('\n') + '"'+ '> ./rawData/' + filename

    output_1 = commands.getoutput(command)
    input.close()
```

When I run my code in PyCharm, it creates a single blank file in my directory called "filename.txt"

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coders-for-hire service. What have you tried so far? Have you done any research into your problem? Have you come across a specific roadblock? Please add all of this information to your question.

Comment: @KernelPanic I have tried a few things, I posted my code in a previous question. I will add it here

Comment: coders-for-hire lol

Comment: please make sure that when you include your code you make it clear exactly where you're running into problems. "Here is a block of code and for some reason it doesn't work" always seems like a good question but people reading it have no idea what "it doesn't work" means in the context of your code.

Comment: @KernelPanic I have included my code. Specifying the problem now.

Comment: Well a couple of problems are immediately apparent: `filename = str(count)` should be referring to `counter_1`, and the only thing in your for-loop is `counter_1 += 1`: you need to indent the following lines if you want them to be executed for each line in input.

Comment: Also, you're going to need to create the rawData directory. `curl` doesn't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead of cURL from within python, as this will make handling the responses much easier. Also, the canonical way to work with files is to use the context manager: `with open(filename) as f`.